# Start Foobar2000 with the play key

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, foobar2000

Can the foobar2000 app be started using the play/pause key?

[image: Keyboard]

Comment: Is using additional software acceptable?

Comment: Yes, it's acceptable

Comment: This is not a duplicate because the OP wants to start the program on the first key press. Controlling foobar with the key comes after that.

Comment: I agree with Daniel. This is not a duplicate

Comment: @DanielB, nixda: How do you figure that this question isn't a duplicate?  The five-year-old question covers both aspects.

Comment: @Scott No, it doesn’t. Multimedia keys cannot be used in `.lnk` shortcuts and the play key doesn’t launch any program by default. The OP doesn’t want to launch it with some “Media Player” key or whatever, but the play key.

Comment: The key to Windows is outside of the standard 104-key ( or whatever is the standard ) subset.  The solution to define the behavior of that key or any key outside of the standard sub-set is the same.